# C++ - Undefined reference to an object

Tags: c++, oop, object, scope

Compiler: MinGW

IDE: Code::Blocks

Platform: Windows XP

External libraries: SDL, SDL_image

What I'm trying to do: Cap the framerate at 60 frames per second using a timer that resets after each loop.

Just a warning, I AM inexperienced with C++, but I've done research and I can't find this kind of error anywhere else. I'm sure it has to do with scope, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Compiler output:
`In function ZN4data6OnLoopEv':|'C:\Documents and Settings\Evan\My Documents\Programming Projects\Roguelike SDLtest 2\OnLoop.cpp|5|undefined reference to 'fps'`

`C:\Documents and Settings\Evan\My Documents\Programming Projects\Roguelike SDLtest 2\OnLoop.cpp|7|undefined reference to 'fps'`

`C:\Documents and Settings\Evan\My Documents\Programming Projects\Roguelike SDLtest 2\OnLoop.cpp|9|undefined reference to 'fps'`

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include "data.h"
bool data::OnExecute()
{
    if (OnInit() == false)
    {
        data::log("Initialization failure.");
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Event Event;
    while(running == true)
    {
        fps.start();
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
        {
            OnEvent(&Event);
        }
        OnRender();
        OnLoop();
        log(convertInt(1000/fps.get_ticks()));
    }
    OnCleanup();
    data::log("Program exited successfully.");
    return 0;
}
```

**data.h:**

```
#ifndef _DATA_H_
    #define _DATA_H_

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "globals.h"

class timer
{
private:
    int     startTicks; //Clock time at timer start
    bool    started;    //Timer status
    int     frame;

public:
    void    Timer();  //Set timer variables

    //Clock actions
    void    start();
    void    stop();

    //Get timer status
    int     get_ticks();

    bool    is_started();   //Checks timer status
    void    incframe();
};

class data
{
private:
    timer fps;
    bool    running;
    SDL_Surface*    display;
    SDL_Surface*    tileset;    //The tileset
    SDL_Rect    clip[255];
    int     spritewidth;
    int     spriteheight;
    bool    mapfloor[80][24];     //Contains the locations of the floor and walls
    int    mapplayer[80][24];    //Contains the location of the player
    SDL_Rect   playersprite;       //Clip value of the sprite that represents the player
    std::string  tilesetdsk;    //Location of the tileset on disk
    std::string     debugfile;
    int     FRAMES_PER_SECOND;  //Max FPS

public:
    data();
    bool    OnExecute();
    bool    OnInit();
    void    OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);
    void    OnLoop();
    void    OnRender();
    void    OnCleanup();
    static  SDL_Surface*    load_image(std::string filename);
    static  void    apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, SDL_Rect* clip);
    void    LoadSprite();   //Determines what sprite is where in the tileset
    bool    levelgen();     //Generates a level
    void    log(std::string);          //**DEBUG** function for logging to file
    void    setvars();
    std::string convertInt(int number);
};
#endif
```

**OnLoop.cpp:**

```
#include "data.h"
void data::OnLoop()
{
    if(fps.get_ticks() < 1000/FRAMES_PER_SECOND)
    {
        SDL_Delay((1000/FRAMES_PER_SECOND) - fps.get_ticks());
    }
    fps.incframe();
}
```

Comment: Show us the `#include` files in each file please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fps` is a variable of type `timer`, declared in `data::OnExecute()`.

However, you also reference `fps` in another method `data::OnLoop()`, where `fps` is out of scope.

To fix this, I recommend making `fps` a member-variable of class `data`.  Then `fps` will always be available inside all the methods of `data`.

Do this by declaring fps right with your other member-variables
(in the `private:` section of `class data`)
Remove the declaration in `data::OnExecute()`.

Comment: Doing this returns C:\Documents and Settings\Evan\My Documents\Programming Projects\Roguelike SDLtest 2\data.h|26|error: field 'fps' has incomplete type|

Comment: @Arctic, where did you get the timer object from? It looks like you forgot to #include a header.

Comment: @Septagram, Hmm? The object is in data.h, I just didn't update the code on here. My bad.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Try adding the line "class timer;" just before the 'data' class definition to declare 'timer' class. Although if it wasn't declared, error message should be different, so I don't guarantee it will help. Sorry, I'm sleepy and my brain is foggy.

Comment: Updated, same error. I can relate to the sleepiness though, haha.

Comment: @ArcticVanguard: Why not move the whole class definition for `class timer` above the definition for `class data`. `class timer` does not depend on `class data` in any way.

Comment: @Omnifarious That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I'll update the code in the OP in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You must move the fps variable declaration to the header file. The fps variable is only defined in the data::OnExecute function scope. If you move it to be a class member, all the methods in the class can access it.

So:
1. Remove the "timer fps;" line from data::OnExecute.
2. Add "timer fps;" below the "private:" in data.h